# How to set a cron job to run every 3 hours

Tags: cron, cpanel

Is this the correct way for setting a cron job to run every 3 hours? 
After setting it this way, cron is executing the command every minute.

[image]

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Change **Minute** to be `0`.  That's it  :)

Note:  you can check your "crons" in http://cronchecker.net/

[Example](http://cronchecker.net/check?utf8=%E2%9C%93&statement=0%20*/3%20*%20*%20*%20script.sh&commit=Check)

Comment: how can i set it to start at particular time as well ? for eg; every 3 hours starting from 12 pm.

Answer (score 43):

Change Minute parameter to 0.

You can set the cron for every three hours as:

**0 */3 * * *   your command here ..**

Answer (score 16):

The unix setup should be like the following:

```
 0 */3 * * * sh cron/update_old_citations.sh
```

good reference for how to set various settings in cron at:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/